# Interpreting "adb shell dumpsys package" output

Tags: android

This command dumps a significant amount of information from my AVD. Here is one snippet:

```
  Package [com.svox.pico] (b1b3a188):
    userId=10035 gids=[1015, 1028]
    pkg=Package{b1be01c8 com.svox.pico}
    codePath=/system/app/PicoTts.apk
    resourcePath=/system/app/PicoTts.apk
    nativeLibraryPath=/data/app-lib/PicoTts
    versionCode=1 targetSdk=18
    versionName=1.0
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{b1be0270 com.svox.pico}
    flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    dataDir=/data/data/com.svox.pico
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2015-02-18 22:38:19
    firstInstallTime=2015-02-18 22:38:19
    lastUpdateTime=2015-02-18 22:38:19
    signatures=PackageSignatures{b1b3a250 [b1b199b8]}
    permissionsFixed=false haveGids=true installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    User 0:  installed=true stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0
    grantedPermissions:
      android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES
```

Questions:

1. What does (b1b3a188) mean? A bracket with magic numbers format appears in every package information.
2. What is the difference between flags and pkgflags?